# Issues with 'django.contrib.staticfiles',

Tags: python, django, url, static

I have a website that works fine on my 'production server' with the url being something akin to:

https://mymain.site.com

I have had my sys admins build a site out for development and that url is:

https://mymain.site.com/development

It is a different IP address, but I believe the URL is wrecking havoc on django routing.   Mostly I notice it in the static section of it.

If I goto the development server settings and change the static url to:

/development/static/

instead of /static/ like it was on production

None of my static files are found.   Since the development server is a VM copy the root on the server for static files is the same.  So if I run with the /development/static as the dev url it fails to load resources.  If I run on my development server with the url being /static/  I am 90% sure it is grabbing the static files from the production server (at a different ip/url).  Not totally sure what the fix is here?  I am loking for any kind of ideas.

I suspect if the url of my development server was something more akin to:

https://mymain.site.for.development/

then this would work right out of the box from the code copied from the VM just repointing a few things.

So what am I missing to get this to work with the right static files?

Answer (score 0):

I use a CDN for my static file hosting and this is how I have my `settings.py` file setup:

```
STATIC_HOST = 'https://cdn.host.com' if not DEBUG else ''
STATIC_URL = STATIC_HOST + '/static/'
```

When I'm developing I'll set `DEBUG = True` and everything works as expected. I would imagine you would have to do something like this:

```
STATIC_HOST = 'https://mymain.site.com' if not DEBUG else 'https://mymain.site.com/development'
STATIC_URL = STATIC_HOST + '/static/'
```

See if something like that would work.